# Transcribing Spanish text (and translating into English) on Death Certificate

Tags: palaeography, death-records, spain

My Great Grandfathers death certificate has this entry:

[image]

I can make out some of the words but not all of them and would appreciate assistance in determining an accurate translation into English for my source citation.

This is what I have so far:

> Otros titulos o datos: Se practica en virtud de esta order recibida en el dia de hoy del jugaddo de instruccion ? dimanante del suma ?? 52 de 1965.

I need the Spanish correct before I attempt to use Deepl to translate it to English.

I know that my Great Grandfather had an accident crossing the road. He was deaf and was hit by a car. He died of internal haemorrhage. My auntie thinks he died on the scene but my mum thinks he died a few days later. Since the death certificate says the location of death was "Hospital Clinico" I assume my mum is correct. This is why I wanted to get an accurate translation of this information in case it says anything pertinent.

Comment: I think "jugaddo de instruccion" is actually "juzgado de instrucción" which is the office of an examining judge that was probably investigating the accident, so it is saying something about an order received from the judge's office.

Comment: To me the first of your ? is the number 1 and the ?? is eso and I think that this would make sense in this context. My Spanish is passable but I am not familiar with the word dimanante.

Comment: @Colin Actually it might be saying: del sumario. And dimanante is translating as: from

Answer (score 2):

Based on the comments provided I have come up with so far:

> Otros titulos o datos: Se practica en virtud de esta order recibida en el dia de hoy del juzgado de instrucción 1 dimanante del sumario 52 de 1965.

Which translates as:

> Other titles or particulars: This is done by virtue of this order received today from the Court of Instruction 1 arising from case number 52 of 1965.

I welcome refinements to this transcription. And of course, this begs the question:

- [Locating case records after death in Valencia, Spain](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/18240/8882)

---

### Update

This is the revised [Deepl](https://www.deepl.com/translator#es/en/Otros%20titulos%20o%20datos%3A%20Se%20practica%20en%20virtud%20de%20carta%20orden%20recibida%20en%20el%20dia%20de%20hoy%20del%20juzgado%20de%20instrucci%C3%B3n%201%2C%20dimanante%20del%20sumario%2052%20de%201965.) translation which uses the new term **carta orden** (as supplied in the other answer). It has been translated into **English (British)** so see what you think:

> Other titles or particulars: This was carried out by virtue of an order received today from the Court of Instruction 1, stemming from case number 52 of 1965.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have made a slip in your proposal: I suggest the correct reading is

Otros titulos o datos: Se practica en virtud de **carta orden** recibida en el dia de hoy del juzgado de instrucción 1, dimanante del sumario 52 de 1965.

"Carta Orden" is a Spanish legal term, it means "mandate" and then later "letter of authority" or even "purchase order".

Comment: Thanks for your proposal which I think looks correct. I have added the updated translation from from Deepl to my own answer too.