# Locating case records after death in Valencia, Spain

Tags: death-records, spain

This question is linked to this one [Transcribing Spanish text (and translating into English) on Death Certificate](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/18237/8882). So the wording below will be updated as and when then actual transcribed text / translation has been verified.

On my Great Grandfathers death certificate there is an entry:

[image]

At the moment we have transcribed this (into English) as:

> Other titles or particulars: This is done by virtue of letter of authority received today from the Court of Instruction 1 arising from **case number 52 of 1965**.

I know that my Great Grandfather was involved in an accident when he was crossing the road. He was hard of hearing and was hit by a vehicle. My mother says he died a short while after the accident but one of my aunties (younger than my mum) thought he died on the scene.

I received the death certificate from the Civil Registry Office in Valencia. Is there any way to gain access to the "case number 52 of 1965" at all? I thought it might confirm.

Comment: Is 1965 the year he died?

Comment: @shoover Yes, 23 Jan 1965

Comment: So the "of 1965" is probably referring to the year. And since he died in January, it makes sense that the ordinal 52nd is so low.

Comment: @shoover I was thinking the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the transcription (I am also translating the "legal" spanish language):

> Other titles or data: (this certificate) is performed thanks to a letter received today from the court number 1 during summary 52 from 1965.

In particular, the court they are referring to is a "juzgado de instrucción" which deals with criminal investigations. Essentially, this death is related to crime, so somehow this one supports the accident hypothesis.

If he would have died in the hospital, the death registry would have been done by the hospital staff. I do believe this strongly supports the hypothesis that he died on scene.

You might be able to further investigate using newspapers:

https://www.abc.es/archivo/periodicos/

http://valenpedia.lasprovincias.es/historia-valencia/

Comment: Thanks. The reason I was not sure was because the certificate said: Lugar: Hospital Clinico.

Comment: At the end the best will be to check the document of the court describing what happened. It might be available in the archives (https://ceice.gva.es/es/web/archivos/inicio) but it is kind of recent...

Comment: Well, this is why I was surprised that the actual court replied as they did (see my own answer). I would that thought they would direct me to those archives if it was going to yield info. It might be worth a shot.

Comment: My auntie also tells me there was an autopsy. And we now know he was buried two days later on 25th. It must have all happened so quickly.

Answer (score 1):

I have come across this website:

[Directory of judicial bodies](https://www.poderjudicial.es/portal/site/cgpj/menuitem.65d2c4456b6ddb628e635fc1dc432ea0/?vgnextoid=b807fb70fc6fe210VgnVCM1000006f48ac0aRCRD&vgnextlocale=en&vgnextfmt=default&vgnextchannel=76cc93841e3eb210VgnVCM100000cb34e20aRCRD&lang_choosen=en)

It mentions the **Juzgado de Instrucción 1**:

[image]

I will try to contact them.

---

### Update

I had this reply by email:

> Buenas tardes, lamentándolo mucho en las actuaciones referenciadas
> de éste Juzgado no constan más datos que los que obran en el Registro
> Civil.

Using DeepL this translates as:

> Good afternoon, I am very sorry to say that in the proceedings referred to
> of this Court do not contain any data other than those contained in the Civil Register.

So it seems that I can't obtain any more information.